# Why can't the Scala compiler give pattern matching warning for nonsealed classes/traits?

Tags: scala, type-safety, trait, pattern-matching

If I use an **un**sealed `trait` or `abstract class` in Scala and then use pattern matching, I wonder, does the compiler not know at compile time for this particular patternmatch what possible implementations of this trait/class are available? So, if it does, could it not give pattern match warnings even though that the `trait`/`abstract class` is not sealed because he knows which types *could* be used, by checking all the possible dependencies/imports?

E.g. if I have an `Option[A]` and I do pattern matching only for `Some[A]` but not for `None`, the compiler will complain, because `Option` is sealed.

If the compiler can't know/resolve that, then why can't he?
And if the compiler (theoretically) can do that, what are the reasons for that it is not used in Scala?
Are there other languages which support that kind of behaviour?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Do you want the compiler to emit a warning if the match expression doesn't cover all possible inputs? Perhaps an example would make your question more clear.

Comment: If anyone can introduce a new subclass, the pattern match can never be exhaustive. E.g. You produce some abstract class `Foo` with subclasses `A`, `B`, and `C`, and all of your pattern matches match only those three. Nothing stops me from adding a new subclass `D` that'll blow up your pattern matches.

Comment: @kdgregory Yes, you got it. I added an example to make it more clear.

Comment: Checking all imports is not sufficient to discover all possible subclasses. Another subclass might be declared in a separate class file that is later loaded during runtime via [`java.lang.ClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Figuring out all subclasses of a class is called Class Hierarchy Analysis, and doing static CHA in a language with dynamic code loading is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Plus, one of the goals of Scala is separate compilation and deployment of independent modules, so the compiler simply cannot know whether or not a class is subclassed in another module, because it never looks at more than one module. (After all, you could compile a module against the interface of some other module without that module even existing on your system!) That's why `sealed` requires all subclasses to be defined in the same compilation unit.

That's also one of the reasons why JVMs can compete so favorably with C++ compilers: C++ compilers are typically static compilers, so they can't in general figure out whether a method is overridden or not, and thus can't inline it. JVMs OTOH, typically are dynamic compilers, they don't need to perform CHA to figure out whether a method is overridden or not, they can just look at the Class Hierarchy at runtime. And even if at a later point in the execution of the program a new subclass comes along that wasn't there before, no big deal, just recompile that piece of code without inlining.

Note: all of this only applies within Scala. The JVM has no notion of `sealed`, so it is perfectly possible to subclass `sealed` classes from *another* JVM language, since there is no way to communicate this to another language. The `sealed` property is recorded in the `ScalaSig` annotation, but other languages' compilers don't take those annotations into account, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

It *can* be done (at least for all classes known at compile time), it's just expensive.  You'd completely destroy incremental compilation, because everything that contains a pattern match would effectively have to be recompiled every time any other file changed.

And what are you buying?  It's a code smell to write pattern matches that need to change frequently when a new derived class is added.  It's a violation of the [open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).  Use inheritance properly and you won't need to write those kinds of pattern matches.  And yes, the open/closed principle also applies to functional languages without class-based inheritance. In fact between features like type classes, multimethods, and just plain higher-order functions, functional languages make extension without modification much easier.

Comment: `It can be done (at least for all classes known at compile time), it's just expensive.` But if the program isn't 100% self-contained (i.e. it depends on external `.jar` files), couldn't you sneak in a new subclass *after* compilation through one of the `jar`s? So the compiler could tell you *"Your pattern matches are exhaustive now, but that may change if any of your dependencies change"* which is pretty worthless since the point of having external dependencies is to be able to update them without recompiling!

Comment: Hence the disclaimer.  In practice, if you were tightly coupled enough to need an exhaustive match on a dependency, external or otherwise, you would want to recompile anyway.

Comment: @Doval Then you should use some form of delegation and let the class being called decide what to do and invert control. This is what OOP was meant for. If you don't want that then you have your current issue.

Comment: @ArtB I fail to see what delegation or inversion of control have to do with this.

Comment: If you want it to work with people being able to add to it externally, then call the class and move the logic into those classes.